Memory transfers not always overlapping with kernel calls
In the following sample code (compiled with --default-stream per-thread), I don't understand why memory transfers are only sometimes executed concurrently with kernel calls:
__global__ void zero(int *Y)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Y[(blockIdx.x + i * gridDim.x) * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x] = 0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = 32 * 100000;
    int *h_X;
    cudaHostAlloc((void **)&h_X, sizeof(int) * n, cudaHostAllocWriteCombined);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        h_X[i] = 0;
    }

    int *X;
    int *Y;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&X, sizeof(int) * n);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&Y, sizeof(int) * n);

#pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(2) firstprivate(n, h_X, X, Y)
    {
#pragma omp section
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                cudaMemcpyAsync(X, h_X, sizeof(int) * n, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
            }
        }
#pragma omp section
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                zero <<<1000, 32>>> (Y);
            }
        }
    }

    cudaFree(X);
    cudaFree(Y);

    cudaFreeHost(h_X);

    return 0;
}

Examples:


I know that concurrent execution is not always guaranteed but I suspect there might be something else going on. The sample code was run on a GeForce GT 635M (CC 2.1) + CUDA 8.0 + Windows 10.

You are using a (rather old) WDDM system -- the WDDM driver performs batching to try and hide the very high latency which can occur with Windows WDDM. On that platform it is the Windows display manager and not the CUDA driver and runtime which handles most of the memory management and task dispatch functions

I understand, but what does that interleaving you see have to do with the batching you describe? It just seems odd to me that the system would run the program like that. I've found that this doesn't happen if I drop OpenMP and manually set up streams, meaning that memory transfers and kernel calls may still be run sequentially but there's no interleaving.

I ran your code on CUDA 11.4 on a K610M GPU (cc3.5) on linux, and consistently got results similar to your first timeline, which I assume you probably think is "expected" behavior.  So I would concur with talonmies that the variability you are seeing is likely due to WDDM batching effects.  WDDM batching isn't well documented, and the behavior is inherently variable, so drawing a direct connection or getting a precise answer would likely be difficult.

I note that in the 2nd timeline you have, it seems that the activity in one thread gets a noticeably earlier start than the other thread.  However this comes about (perhaps through OMP thread variability) may also influence the variable behavior of WDDM batching.

Thanks @RobertCrovella for your independent test
